# How to make API endpoint for when there are multiple query parameters that have same key?

Tags: mysql, rest, get, api-design

I'm working on a web app using NodeJS and Express (SQL/MySQL for the database), based on this tutorial for a REST API: https://www.bezkoder.com/node-js-rest-api-express-mysql/ (just replacing 'tutorials' with 'Employees').

I want the user to be able to search the database using multiple query parameters, sometimes with the same key (for example, get all Employees with lasName Smith *and* lastName Garcia). So the request URL might look like this:

```
http://localhost:8081/api/employees/?lastname=Smith&lastname=Garcia
```

The way I've designed my controller function ('getAll') is like this:

```
exports.getAll = (req, res) => {

    if (req.query.hasOwnProperty('lastname')) {
        const lastname = req.query.lastname;

       // ... calls to the model class function to retrieve from DB
```

And I have if-conditions for all the other properties/parameters (firstname, position, teamname, etc.), so the problem is I have no way of detecting multiple of the *same* query parameter.

How would I go about fixing this? Thank you for any help/advice!

Comment: Instead of sending multiple occurrences of lastname in the query string you should use a separator for multiple values - `http://localhost:8081/api/employees/?lastname=Smith,Garcia` or `http://localhost:8081/api/employees/?lastname=Smith|Garcia`

Comment: @nnichols How would I go about altering how the query string is constructed to begin with? Right now it's automatically generated by the HTTP request (I think, my understanding is a little hazy). Is that something I would have to change on the Database side?

Comment: Who and/or what is accessing the API endpoint? They/it will have to construct the request appropriately. When you are processing the request you can just split the string based on your chosen separator.

Comment: Ah I understand now! Yea it's being called/accessed by my front-end and using a fetch call pass the URL into my backend. So I just have to construct that URL in my script. Now the problem is writing an SQL command but that's another story haha. Thanks!